# C program to do a find and replace in a file

Tags: c

I wrote a program that writes to a file, then does a find and replace on that file, with the condition that the new word must have the same length as the old one.

The program will read chunks of the file into a buffer, perform the find and replace on the buffer, write it to a copy, when the original file is at the end, it'll copy back the edited text back into the original.

If it did not read an entire line (meaning that the word could be split between 2 reads), it rolls back the file handler backwards by the length of the old word. This is the part I'm interested in, do I roll it back by `length`, or `length - 1`, the current way seems to work correctly, which is `length`.

Note that this is a school assignment and I'll be presenting it in front of my teacher, are there any possible bugs? I want to make sure it's doing what I think it's doing.

Here is the code, I made the buffer size extremely small on purpose to test if it's working, I'll change it to something appropriate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define WORD_SIZE 24

void write_to_file(const char *s);
void replace_word(const char *s);
void clear(void);

int main(void){
    const char file_name[] = "text.txt";
    int c;
    puts("Enter 'w' to write to the file, 'r' to replace a word");
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch(c){
        case 'w':
            clear();
            write_to_file(file_name);
            break;
        case 'r':
            clear();
            replace_word(file_name);
            break;
        default:
            clear();
            printf("Invalid command:%c\n", c);
            break;
        }
        puts("Enter 'w' to write to the file, 'r' to replace a word");
    }
    return 0;
}

void write_to_file(const char *s){
    puts("Enter input:");
    FILE *in_file;
    if((in_file = fopen(s, "w")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        fputc(c, in_file);
    }

    fclose(in_file);
    puts("Successfully written to the file");
}

void replace_word(const char *s){
    char old_word[WORD_SIZE];
    char new_word[WORD_SIZE];

    puts("Enter the word you want to replace");
    fgets(old_word, sizeof(old_word), stdin);
    old_word[strlen(old_word) - 1] = '\0';
    puts("Enter the new word");
    fgets(new_word, sizeof(new_word), stdin);
    new_word[strlen(new_word) - 1]  = '\0';

    if(strlen(old_word) != strlen(new_word)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't replace \"%s\" with \"%s\":\nThe length is not the same\n", old_word, new_word);
        return;
    }
    FILE *original_file;
    FILE *copy;

    if((original_file = fopen(s, "r")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((copy = fopen("copy.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        perror("text");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    int word_len = strlen(old_word);
    int word_frequency = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, original_file)){
        char *init_loc = buffer;
        while((buffer = strstr(buffer, old_word))){
            memcpy(buffer, new_word, word_len);
            word_frequency++;
        }
        buffer = init_loc;
        fputs(buffer, copy);
        if(!strchr(buffer, '\n')){
            fseek(original_file, -(word_len), SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    printf("'%s' found %i times\n", old_word, word_frequency);

    fclose(original_file);
    fclose(copy);

    if((original_file = fopen(s, "w")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((copy = fopen("copy.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        perror("text");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(copy)) != EOF){
        fputc(c, original_file);
    }

    fclose(original_file);
    fclose(copy);
    remove("copy.txt");
    free(buffer);

    if(word_frequency > 0){
        puts("Word replaced successfully");
    }
    else{
        puts("No words were replaced");
    }
}

void clear(void){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && (c != EOF));
}
```

Comment: "do I roll it back by length, or length - 1". The way to answer that is testing, testing and more testing. Write unit tests to generate as many test combinations as you can.

Comment: If `old_word` is the same word as `new_word`, it loops infinitely.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Didn't think of that, I made a condition that the words must be different. I used `if(!strcmp(old_word, new_word))`, that is the correct way, right?

Comment: I agree. I think that such checks are necessary. Or you can just shift the restart position of the search.

Comment: Also If the word length is more than 10 characters(buffer size), this approach can not handle it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Like I said, 10 is just a test value to make sure small buffers are working. I'll make sure `BUFFER_SIZE` is always bigger than `WORD_SIZE` in the final version.

Comment: If the buffer size is small, you can not actually use `strstr`. However, perhaps even 1 byte is okay to change the approach(not use `strstr`). But if there is no newline , it is easier to simply extend the buffer and continue reading (perhaps like `getline`).

Comment: `getline` was originally what I was using. But I need to present this assignment on a Windows computer that won't have the function since it's not part of the standard.

Comment: What I'm talking about is to extend the `buffer` (E.g, Using `realloc`). It is not to use `getline`.

Comment: Also You are retracting the reading position when there is no newline(`if(!strchr(buffer, '\n')){`), but at this time you are writing(`fputs(buffer, copy);`) already, so the new file is incorrect.

Comment: `fgets(old_word, sizeof(old_word), stdin);
    old_word[strlen(old_word) - 1] = '\0';` allows a hacker exploit when `old_word[0] == 0`.

Comment: Curious, why use `int` in `int word_len = strlen(old_word);` vs `unsigned`, `size_t`, or even `char`?

Comment: `while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch(c){` should not call `clear()` when `c == '\n'`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What would be the correct solution? I tried going backwards in the copy file too, but that didn't work.

Comment: I think that what's easy with your approach is buffer expansion.